# How to print Python installation directory to the output?

Tags: python, path

Let's say Python is installed in the location

> C:\TOOLS\COMMON\python\python252

I want to print this location in the output of my program. Please let me know can I do this.

Comment: "this is not a home work" - no need to be paranoid :-)

Answer (score 39):

you can use

```
import sys, os
os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
```

but remember than in Unix systems the "installation" of a program is usually distributed along the following folders:

- /usr/bin (this is what you'll probably get)
- /usr/lib
- /usr/share
- etc.

Comment: I forgot the "dirname", sorry ^_^ now it's fixed

Answer (score 6):

Maybe either of these will satisfy you:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.prefix)
/usr
>>> print(sys.path)
['', '/usr/lib/python25.zip', '/usr/lib/python2.5', '/usr/lib/python2.5/plat-linux2',
'/usr/lib/python2.5/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.5/lib-dynload', 
'/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages', 
'/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Numeric', '/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gst-0.10',
'/var/lib/python-support/python2.5', '/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gtk-2.0', 
'/var/lib/python-support/python2.5/gtk-2.0']
```

Comment: >>> print(sys.prefix)      in python > 3.6.3

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.prefix
```

See the documentation for the [`sys` module](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html) for more details.

Comment: Worked for me on Windows, but not Linux, where it gave /usr instead of /usr/bin