# Calling python in conda environment (2.7.6) activate defaults to python in system (3.4.6)

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I've created a concoct_env to run python 2.7.6. The default python on my system is python 3.4.6.

So I activate the concoct environment.

```
user1@workmachine:~/anaconda3/envs/concoct_env$ source activate concoct_env
```

I check which python version that will be called, looks fine.

```
(concoct_env) user1@workmachine:~/anaconda3/envs/concoct_env$ which python
/home/user1/anaconda3/envs/concoct_env/bin/python
```

But when I call python or check the python version, it shows the default python installed on my system.

```
(concoct_env) user1@workmachine:~/anaconda3/envs/concoct_env$ python --version
 Python 3.4.6

(concoct_env) user1@workmachine:~/anaconda3/envs/concoct_env$ python
Python 3.4.6 (default, Mar 22 2017, 12:26:13) [GCC] on linux
```

Is there something I'm missing in the PATH parameters in my bashrc? Thanks in advance for nay help.

Edited to add:

How I create the test environment

```
conda create -n concoct_env python=2.7.6
```

How my bashrc file looks like:

```
export PATH=/home/user1/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

Location of python 2.7.6 in conda environment (same as indicated in "which python"

```
Python 2.7.6 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, May 27 2014, 14:50:58) 
>>> os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
'/home/user1/anaconda3/envs/concoct_env/bin'
```

Comment: Could you add the command you ran to create your python 2.7.6 Anaconda virtual environment so I can try and reproduce your setup?

Comment: HI @PicoutputCls, thanks for your reply. I've added the details to my initial post.

Comment: Thanks @jonoave, I've just created a setup like yours and everything seems to be fine. The issue might be something configured in your shell environment. Could you to post the output from the `env` command? Could you also confirm the location of the `python` binary that is being used in your virtual environment by following the instructions in the answer to this post: [how to print python location(where python is install) in the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270537/how-to-print-python-locationwhere-python-is-install-in-the-output#1270554)

Comment: Hi @PicoutputCls, I've added the python location - it is the location when I typed "which python°. As for the env output, it is a pretty long list to post. Maybe you can tell me how it is supposed to look like or what should i be looking for related to conda? Thanks!

Comment: I am bit confused. Firstly, you say that your python 2.7.6 virtual environment is called `test_env` but I see from your paths that you actually seem to be using an Anaconda environment called `concoct_env`. Are you sure you've been working in the right environment? Secondly, the output from checking the binary location in Python (using the instructions I linked above) and from your previous `python` output are inconsistent: `Python 2.7.6 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, May 27 2014, 14:50:58)` vs `Python 3.4.6 (default, Mar 22 2017, 12:26:13) [GCC] on linux` How is this?

Comment: Hi @PicoutputCls, the python 3.4.6 is the default python installed in the system. The Python 2.7.6 is the python installed through conda, in virtual environment.

Sorry for the confusion about test and concoct_env, everything is in concoct_env, I edited the environment names manually as they where named differently. I have fixed the edits in the main post.

Comment: Ok, I figured out the problem. Apparently there is entry in the .alias file for "python=(system-installed python)". I removed that entry and now things work fine.

Comment: You can post that as an answer.