# Is it possible to use Selenium WebDriver in Libreoffice Calc?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to use Selenium in Libreoffice but this error message always appears:

> <class 'ImportError'>: No module named 'selenium' (or 'selenium.webdriver' is unknown)

How to fix it?

I already have Selenium installed.

Comment: What environment are you writing your code in. Is there a python scripting section for LibreOffice?

Comment: I'm using a macro tool in libreoffice calc, as it has support for python. The code is executed by a button that runs a macro in python, the macro reads the current cell and fills a form on the website with this information from the spreadsheet.

Comment: The python you are using with LibreOffice is probably not the same one that has Selenium installed. You can check [where the python executable is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270537/how-to-print-python-installation-directory-to-the-output) to confirm this

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked.

Comment: Sure, glad I could help. I'm assuming you installed Selenium into the correct env?

Comment: Selenium was installed in another directory,

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's now possible in LibreOffice Calc to drive Python Requests and Selenium.
You must install the [OAuth2OOo](https://prrvchr.github.io/OAuth2OOo/) extension.
Enjoy....

More informations:

- [Driving Firefox with Calc formulas](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=110202)
- [New Calc AddIns for HTML    Microdata](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?p=538997#p538997)

Disclaimer: I am the developer of the CalcAddIns.